# running asp.net project on vs community for mac

Tags: asp.net, macos

I am having trouble running an asp.net project on vs community for mac, I am stuck on this error now and I am trying to figure out if presentation core is a built in windows file that I need, or if it is even possible to run the project with out running windows through a virtual box

Error: Could not load the file 'PresentationCore'.

Comment: An ASP.NET project? Not ASP.NET Core? What framework are you running on?

Comment: Hi Mason, it is an ASP .NET project

Comment: Correct, Not Core

Comment: The old .NET Framework based ASP.NET does not run directly on any platform except Windows. You *may* be able to run it via [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/). Your best bet is to run a VM to develop this app, or re-implement it on top of ASP.NET Core running on .NET Core.

Comment: I see, Thank you for you quick feedback!